# SQLBuddy: How to select database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlbuddy

I have the following sql which I want to import with SQLBuddy.

However I get an error telling that no database selected.

Could anyone tell me what line I need to add please?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_banner` (
  `bid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'banner',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imptotal` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `impmade` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  `...
...
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`bid`),
  KEY `viewbanner` (`showBanner`),
  KEY `idx_banner_catid` (`catid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `jos_banner`
--

INSERT INTO `jos_banner` (`bid`, `cid`, `type`, `name`, `alias`, `imptotal`, `impmade`, `clicks`, `imageurl`, `clickurl`, `date`, `showBanner`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `editor`, `custombannercode`, `catid`, `description`, `sticky`, `ordering`, `publish_up`, `publish_down`, `tags`, `params`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'banner', 'OSM 1', 'osm-1', 0, 47, 0, 'osmbanner1.png', 'http://www.opensourcematters.org', '2004-07-07 15:31:29', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', 13, '', 0, 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', ''),
(2, 1, 'banner', 'OSM 2', 'osm-2', 0, 49, 0, 'osmbanner2.png', 'http://www.opensourcematters.org', '2004-07-07 15:31:29', 0, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', 13, '', 0, 2, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', ''),
(3, 2, '', 'Joomla!', 'joomla', 0, 1363, 0, '', 'http://www.joomla.org', '2009-05-29 ...
...
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the SQLBuddy homepage you need to create a database first, name it as whatever you want and then from the left sidebar select your new created database, then from the top menu select `Query`, paste your sql and go on!

Answer (score 2):

`use databasename;`

Answer (score 0):

Like it says: select a database.
Say your database is called ShinsBlog, add this to the start of your code:

> use ShinsBlog;